# iPhoneSimulator: is booted but getenv returned nil for test connection socket path

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode-ui-testing

The complete error is `iPhoneSimulator: Sim iPhone 5 is booted but getenv returned nil for test connection socket path.`
I get this while running tests with [snapshot](http://github.com/fastlane/snapshot/).
And because of this (I think) my tests fail.

I've already tried resetting my simulators, but it didn't make any difference.

Why is this caused?

**UPDATE**: This happens when taking snapshots for more than one language.
I tried making snapshots for just "en-US" and it worked just fine. Then I tried "es-ES" and worked fine too. But whenever I try to make snapshots for both it fails.

Comment: maybe you should create an issue within fastlane repo. I have the same problem.

Comment: @netshark1000 I've already did it, check: [link](https://github.com/fastlane/snapshot/issues/337) Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is fixed in `snapshot` now by restarting the simulator after each run: https://github.com/fastlane/snapshot/issues/337

Comment: I was going to add this right now, glad you did it before! Thanks!